# Install github organization private package using docker build

Tags: python, git, docker, github, ssh

I am part of an organization X. Here, we have a python package which is added into requirements.txt. I have access to this repository.

When I am doing pip install https://github.com/X/repo.git, it is working fine. Because it was using my git identity present in the host or my local machine.

However, when I do pip install with docker as follows

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt


# Install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git openssh-client

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/X/repo_name.git@setup#egg=repo_name

# Install Dependencies
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

# Configure server
ENV HOST="0.0.0.0"
ENV PORT=5000

# CMD
ENTRYPOINT uvicorn app:app --host ${HOST} --port ${PORT}

# Remove SSH Key
RUN rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

it is throwing the following error
[image]

I have set the ssh key in github as well using following [approach](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

But, when I do `ssh -T username@github.com` it is throwing `Permission denied`. But, I have the owner rights of the repository which is under an organization.

Not sure, how to resolve this issue!

Comment: check your role in Organization.

Answer (score 0):

> when I do `ssh -T username@github.com` it is throwing Permission denied

It will *always* throw "`Permission denied`" is you are using `username@github.com` instead of `git@github.com`, since the 'username' part is inferred from your public key registered to your GitHub profile. But the remote user for SSH query *must* be `git`, a service account for GitHub.

Second, if you import your private key in the image, make sure to use multi-stage build, as described in "[Access Private Repositories from Your Dockerfile Without Leaving Behind Your SSH Keys](https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/)" from [Vladislav Supalov](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vsupalov/).

And make sure to set the [right permission to `~/.ssh` elements](https://superuser.com/a/1559867/141).